# Select an item in a listbox and modify that same item - python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

So I am studying for my `tkinter` exam and I am having this problem where I have this `Listbox` (`lbtarefas`), and I have this button (`btn_adicionar`), and whenever I write something on this `textvariable` (`txt_tarefa`) from this entry (`tarefa_entry`) it is added to the `listbox`.
Now I have this event binding on selecting something from the `Listbox`, it appears again on the entry (`tarefa_entry`), now what I have to do it to edit that text and when I click the same button again (`btn_adicionar`) it should upload/modify the same item that was selected previously on the `Listbox`. But how??? sos my exam is on monday

Thank you so much in advance!

```py
#function i have on the btn_adicionar
def adicionar ():
    tarefa = txt_tarefa.get()
    lbtarefas.insert(END, tarefa)
    tarefa_entry.delete(0, END)
    numerar()

#function i have on the event binding:
def selec_item(event):
    ind = lbtarefas.curselection()
    text = lbtarefas.get(ind)
    txt_tarefa.set(text)

#listbox
lbtarefas = Listbox(window, width=25, height=10, selectmode="multiple") 
lbtarefas.place(x=20, y=20)
lbtarefas.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', selec_item)

#Entry
txt_tarefa = StringVar()
tarefa_entry = Entry(panel_tarefa, width=50, bd=3, relief= 'sunken', textvariable=txt_tarefa)
tarefa_entry.place(x=50, y=10)

#Button
btn_adicionar = Button(window, text="Adicionar",fg = "blue", height=2, width=15,relief="raised", justify='center',command= adicionar)
btn_adicionar.place(x = 10, y=10)
```

Comment: the numerar() function calling is just a function i have to update the number of 'tarefas' on the listbox

Comment: The easiest solution would be to delete the current item and add edited item to the position. But I would like to know what you expect to happen when the user selects more than 1 item in the listbox.

Comment: Change this tarefa = txt_tarefa.get() to tarefa =tarefa_entry.get()